# How can I see how many child-tasks a pool worker is currently executing?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I'm using Celery in Django and the workers are eating up all of the memory of my Dynos in Heroku. Setting the [`--max-tasks-per-child`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/reference/cli.html?highlight=max-tasks-per-child) seems to be a valid solution but I can't seem to find what the ramifications of setting a low number might be.

So, I wanted to know if it's possible to either monitor the amount of child-tasks a worker is currently running or log this data somewhere.

Comment: The [flower](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tool can be used to monitor your workers. The impact of setting `--max-tasks-per-child` is dependent on a lot of factors - how long does your app or worker take to initialise? How long does each task take on average? How many workers do you have? What is your desired/expected throughput?

Comment: Okay, I've got flower installed, but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking out for. Any tips or articles would be very helpful. The flower documentation doesn't seem to provide anything on enhancing performance.